# XML Schema: How to handle different occurrences in an unordered list?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

What kind of choice block(or something comparable) matches the following XML documents:

**Example 1**

```
<root>
   <multiple1 />
   <multiple2 />
   <multiple2 />

   <single1 />

   <multiple1 />
   <multiple2 />

   <single2 />

   <multiple1 />
</root>
```

**Example 2**

```
<root>
   <single1 />

   <multiple2 />
   <multiple1 />
</root>
```

**Example 3**

```
<root>
   <multiple1 />
   <multiple1 />

   <single2 />

   <multiple1 />
   <multiple1 />
</root>
```

**Requirements:**

- The elements `<single1>` and `<single2>` must occur 0 or 1 time
- The occurrence of the elements `<multiple1>` and `<multiple2>` is unbounded(>=0)
- Any sequence/order of the three elements is allowed

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with XSD 1.0.

Comment: @Monolo: I am not sure I agree. If the question is 'how can I do X with technology Y' I'd say that 'It is not possible to do it' IS an answer.

Comment: @Monolo: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95764/should-one-accept-negative-answers (different opinions...)